# Primes with prime digits and prime sum of the digits

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, perfect-numbers

I don't know if this concept is already defined, I consider the number $n$ to be a perfect prime (weak) if $n$ is a prime, its digits are primes and the sum of the digits is prime. Every one digit prime is a perfect prime (weak) and it's clear that every perfect prime has to be a combination of elements in the set $ \{2,3,5,7 \}$. Some examples of these are 23,223,227,537233,777277.
So my question is, there always exist infinite $(d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4) \in \mathbb{Z}^4  $ such that
$$ 2d_1 +3d_2 + 5d_3 + 7d_4  $$ is prime and some combination of the $d_i$ $2,3,5,7$ is prime?

The perfect primes (strong) or perfect primes complete the "perfect", as the product of the digits can not be prime we put the condition that the product is a perfect number $(6,28,496,...)$
For example, 23 is a perfect prime (weak) and $2*3=6$ a perfect number, so $23$ is a perfect prime. $227$ is a perfect prime (weak) and $2*2*7=28$ a perfect number, so $227$ is a perfect prime.
The formula $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)  $ with $p$ and $2^p-1$ prime generates perfect numbers, but it is not known that every perfect number is the form $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)  $. No odd perfect number is known, it's still an open problem. If every perfect number is even of the form $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)  $ as before then the only perfect primes are $23$ and $227$ because the next perfect number after $28$ would be of the form $2^aP$ with $P$ a prime larger than $7$, so $P$ must have $2$ or more digits, then we can not make a number with digits $ \{2,3,5,7 \}$ sucht the product is $2^aP$

Comment: Nice problem, It could be also that it is perfect prime when it is prime and the sum of its digits is prime. I recall that **perfect numbers** are  positive integers that are equal to the sum of its proper divisors.

Comment: Note that every perfect number larger than $28$ has a prime factor larger than $7$ (odd perfect numbers must have a large prime factor as well, if there is one) , so to get another "strong prime", you have to make a modification. But "weak primes" should exist infinite many and we can probably easily find examples thousands of digits long.

Comment: My intuition is that there exist infinite weak perfect primes, but I would need a prove

Comment: I do not think that there is a (formal) proof , but finding many extremely large such primes should remove every doubt.